# How to add Comment in CSV Header using JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I want to add a comment on Header fields of CSV File generated by Javascript

Also, I have Searched out for these requirements but can't find any solutions

Here is code that's using for generating CSV  File using Javascript

```js
var data = [
       ['123'],
       ['346'],
       ['789'],
       ['Test1'],
       ['Test2']
    ];


    function download_csv() {
        var csv = 'ID\n';
        data.forEach(function(row) {
                csv += row.join(',');
                csv += "\n";
        });

        console.log(csv);
        var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
        hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
        hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
        hiddenElement.download = 'test.csv';
        document.getElementById('container').appendChild(hiddenElement);
        hiddenElement.click();
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="download_csv()">Download CSV</button>
<div id="container" style="display:none;"></div>
```

I want to Add Header Comment like [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DS4oH.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to achieve this using CSV. However, you can resort to writing the file as XLXS as commenting is an application specific feature.